# Attempt dereference Null - Error

Tags: apex

I have below code where I am getting a null reference error. I can't understand why my if clause shows faulty.

```
for(List<hierarchyNode> hierLists: hier)
            for(hierarchyNode hierNode: hierLists)
                if(hierNode.nType != 'Terr' && users.get(hierNode.UserId).Name!=null) // This line throws error
                    hierNode.Value += ' ' + users.get(hierNode.UserId).Name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because if `users.get(hierNode.UserId)` this map return null then you will get a null pointer exception.

You should update your if condition and check the value first

```
if(hierNode.nType != 'Terr' && users.containsKey(hierNode.UserId) && users.get(hierNode.UserId).Name!=null)
```

Comment: I will accept the answer in 9 mins as forum throws a validation for 9 mins minimum to accept an answer. Thanks for your quick help. :)

Comment: @SFDC_Learner glad I can help.